# Posting Using ajax in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, post, cakephp-2.0

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(".addquestion").unbind('click').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(1);console.log(this);
        var context = $(this).parent();
        var question = $("#QuestionName",context).val();
        var sid = $("input[name='sid']",context).val();
        var location = $("input[name='Image']",context).val();
        var options = [];
        options[0] = $("input[name='TextOption1']",context).val();
        options[1] = $("input[name='TextOption2']",context).val();
        options[2] = $("input[name='TextOption3']",context).val();
        options[3] = $("input[name='TextOption4']",context).val();
        options[4] = $("input[name='TextOption5']",context).val();
        var answer = $('input:radio[name=Option]:checked').val();
        var data = {"Question":question,"options":options,"answer":answer,"sid":sid,"Location":location}

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        var successCallBack= function()
        {
        alert('saved');

        };
        var errorCallBack=function()
        {
        alert('errorCallBack');

        };

        $.ajax({
                url: "questions/add/19",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                success: successCallBack,
                error: errorCallBack
         });

    });
});
```

What should be in my controller. To capture his posted string

Answer (score 1):

You can submit form using jquery

see code here

http://lab.yogeshsaroya.com/submit-form-using-ajax-in-php/